# Texstudio user-defined hover preview

Tags: texstudio

When hovering the cursor over the starting symbol of inline math mode, `$`, or over `\begin{equation}`, Texstudio gives a preview of the typeset math.  I love this feature, but it only works in these two cases.  Mostly I use `\[` for math, or the `align` environment, so I would like to add my own environments to trigger this preview.

Someone else felt the same way and opened this ticket on Sourceforge, and it was closed as "implemented".  But then how does one do it?

http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/322/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I have 2.5.2, same as you.  How do you add new triggers?

Comment: @JeremyVoltz I don't think I had to add any new triggers. In the configuration window is a section “Custom Highlighting” wher e you can specify new environments to be from type “Numbers”, though this section is empty, so I don’t think that has anything to do with it. It seems to only work when I hover over the `\end{align}` part, *not* the formula itself or the `\begin{align}` part.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, you're right, it works for the \end{align}.  Does it work for you on \\[?  That seems to be a no go, which is what I most want it for.

Comment: @JeremyVoltz Correction: It works on `\begin` and `\end`, not on `align` or the formula. No it does not work with `[`, but if you use `amsmath` anyway you can use the equivalent `equation*` environment instead.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, ah, good idea!  I can just replace them all with equation*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeXstudio provides preview images for math content inside of

- `$ … $` (while hovering over the first `$`) and
- all<sup>†</sup> `amsmath` environments while hovering over the `\begin` or the `\end` part.  It won’t work when the mouse only hovers over the name of the environment or the formula itself.

It won’t work with the display-math `\[ … \]` syntax, but as this is only a short cut to the `equation*` environment when `amsmath` is loaded, you could replace the syntax`\[ … \]` with `\begin{equation*} … \end{equation*}` if you need the preview here as well.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>The `alignat` environment produces a preview with misplaced sub-formula parts and (if activated) equation numbers.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The math recognition for tooltip preview will be improved in the next release. This includes hovering over `\[` and over the environment name (e.g. `align` in `\begin{align}`). Furthermore there will be better detection of multi-line formulas.

Comment: Should this be implemented for `align` now? I am using 2.8.6 on Windows and it doesn't seem to work. Working fine for `equation`.

Comment: @kennyB: There was a bug preventing the tooltip for a number of environments. This will be fixed in the next release (>2.8.8).